# capturing response header in Jmeter and use it as variable in another request

Tags: jmeter

I want to capture response Header ***Location*** : specifically 100 number so i can use it as variable in another request. How can i do this ?

**Request**

Remote Address: 57.98.32.25:80

Request URL:http://57.98.32.25/new_events

Request Method:POST

Status Code:200 OK

**Response Headers**

Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:close 
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:105
Content-Type:text/html;
Date:Thu, 27 Aug 2015 06:37:31 GMT 
Location:http://57.98.32.25/new_events/**100**
Server:Apache/2.2.15

Answer (score 13):

You can do it via [Regular Expression Extractor](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743642-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jmeter) configured as follows:

- Field to check: `Response Headers`
- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `location`
- Regular Expression: `new_events/(\d+)`
- Template: `$1$`

[image: Regular Expression Extractor]

You may also need to switch "Apply to" value to "Main sample and sub-samples" if there are redirects and the Location header is not available in the main sample, use [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to determine it.

Refer extracted value as `${location}` or `${__V(location)}` where required.

Comment: Thanks. Are the extracted variables available across thread groups or only within a test group? I have multiple thread groups. Can I pass parameter extracted from thread group 1 to say thread group 2?

Comment: Only within one thread group and even more, only within a single thread (virtual user), if you want to pass a JMeter Variable to another thread no matter in the same or different Thread Group you will either need to convert it into a JMeter Property using [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) or go for [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)